# How to Implement Touch events on Graphs in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, graph, charts

I am using MicroCharts to display various types of graphs in my android application. Microchart's Graphs are really Beauftiful and Light However I Want to Drill down on a particular Entry. 
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BjWi.png) In the image, for e.g i want to open an activity after clicking on "January" which will show some further details about the entry. Is there any way to achieve this? I came up with a method which will differentiate the color we'll click but have no idea how to get started.